# How can I use the included Axios Type definitions for dependency injection in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, axios

I'm trying to create a function that will accept an optional parameter for an axios instance. I've tried the following, using `AxiosInstance` but when webpack tries to transpile the TypeScript it throws this error: `TS2304: Cannot find name 'AxiosInstance'`

It works, kinda, when I directly import the type declaration:

`import { AxiosInstance } from "../../node_modules/axios/index.d";`

But this feels like a very ugly solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Example:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const loadFromAPI = (
    url: string, 
    param: string, 
    id: number, 
    axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({baseURL: url})
): Promise<any> => {
   return new Promise( (resolve: (res: any) => void, reject: (err: any) => void) => { 
    /* ... */
  });
};
```

See: [Axios Type Definitions](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts)

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are not importing *AxiosInstance* interface.

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import just a type of AxiosInstance:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import type { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow! Please explain your answer a little more to help future readers. Please also explain why this answer is different (and/or better) than any existing answers